Unable to create an Azure Machine Learning Workspace using the CLI
I am currently trying to create an azure Machine Learning workspace with the CLI. I used the code:
az ml workspace create --name "rg-dp100-labs" --resource-group "rg-dp100-labs"

I got the following error.
Code: ValidationError
Message: Missing dependent resources in workspace json
Target: workspace
Exception Details: (Invalid) Missing dependent resources in workspace json
Code: Invalid    
Message: Missing dependent resources in workspace json    
Target: workspace

Only the KeyVault and Storage accounts were created. Referring to this link on Microsoft Learn, I found that others also have the same issue. Even a Google search gave me the same code as written above. lease, is anyone experiencing the same issue and has solved it? I think it is a recent problem.

Yes, it seems to be a general issue with the extension ml in version 2.26.0. I solved it by running these commands one by one in a local bash:
az extension remove -n azure-cli-ml
az extension remove -n ml
az extension add -n ml --version=2.25.0

After running these commands, you can run the commands to provision the resource group (don't use the same group name you used previously, use a new one) and the ml workspace:
az group create --name "new-group-name" --location "eastus"
az ml workspace create --name "mlw-dp100-labs" -g "new-group-name"

Remember to do it in a local bash, because the Cloud Shell in Azure does not allow modifying the version of ml. Here a screenshot that it works
Creating a ML Workspace
